# Apple Watch openparentapplication: reply: receives Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain Code=5

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

I have created a smaller project for Apple watch to communicate with it’s parent application it’s worked.

So I have created a Watch kit extension in my existing iOS project but when from Watch side it call openparent application in reply block it receives

“**Error: Error Domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 5.)**”.

What does this error means? Is there any target issue? Please find the code below:

**Watch kit side :**

```
- (IBAction)satusButtonClicked {

    NSLog(@"StausButtonClicked");
    NSDictionary *senddict=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[@"5",@"Two",@"Three"] forKeys:@[@"1",@"2",@"3"]];
    [InterfaceController openParentApplication:senddict reply:^(NSDictionary *replyInfo, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"ReplyReceived : %lu",(unsigned long)[replyInfo count]);
        NSLog(@"Reply Info: %@", replyInfo);
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

}
```

**iOS side :**

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *))reply
{
    NSLog(@"Watckit call received");
    reply(@{@"Score": @"234"});
```

Comment: Having the same problem myself. Does your main iOS app have multiple targets at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
In the info.plist, I had "Application Does Not Run in Background" set to YES. This caused the problem. Changing that setting to NO fixed it.
```

Answered from here:
[iOS Error: FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 5. What does this mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28920969/ios-error-fbsopenapplicationerrordomain-error-5-what-does-this-mean)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Another team added this property to the pilst which broke our WK openParent calls.  Without your post we would have spent hours figuring out what changed.